# Creating a Managed Package with a Connected App

Tags: managed-package, connected-apps, isv

We are trying to create a managed package that contains a connected app. The purpose of this is to submit it for security review and eventually be listed on AppExchange.

The connected app just syncs data both ways with our web app. Clients connect with OAuth from our app, and then our server syncs data back and forth. So there isn't really any code on Salesforce itself, Salesforce just provides the client ID, secret, callback, etc. - like any standard OAuth integration.

We are trying to follow the documentation to make a managed package but it is all very confusing and not straightforward at all. Different organizations, namespaces, etc. For example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_connected_app.htm) I have followed the steps up to 4 - how can there be a "source" for a connected app? How do I navigate to this or pull it? What are the requirements for different orgs holding different things and how are these orgs even made?

If someone who has been through this could provide info or steps for a beginner to accomplish the goal of creating a 2GP with a connected app, that would be much appreciated!

Bonus: The current connected app uses the tooling API to create APEX classes and triggers. These are only for making a webhook that notifies our server when certain objects change. However, my understanding with the 2GP is that it would be better to have these classes and triggers packaged alongside the connected app rather than have it create them - how would one go about doing this?

Comment: The first question to ask is do you need a separate connected app per install of your package? For our use case (a mobile app) we have one Connected App on our Partner Business Org (PBO), used to connect to our package on whichever org is required. Packaging Connected Apps, especially with 2GP, is non-trivial. Your use case sounds like one for using a PBO Connected App. YMMV.

Comment: @PhilW Our connected app works will all clients, but each client needs to go through to OAuth flow to authorize their org to connect to our solution. So I think our use case is similar to yours? For reference, a simplified way to think of our use case is a web app where clients can create a document and associate this document with an opportunity on SF. Then for example, when various properties change in the document, the connected app updates various custom properties on the Opportunity, and when certain properties on the Opportunity change, the connected app updates our document.

Comment: Sounds very similar, though does depend on the authentication. For us, we expect the mobile app user to login with a web flow (OAuth 2, of course, granting API access etc.). If you have this sort of situation then consider one, shared Connected App. The best place to define this is on your PBO because that org won't disappear (unless your business does!).

Comment: @PhilW Yes, that's almost exactly like our system. We do have a PBO and it sounds like creating the connected app here is what we need to do. Do you know the steps one would take to bundle this connected app into a 2GP? We tried following some of the SF documentation, but its unclear where each piece goes in each org, it says to "pull the source from the org" but there is no source on SF for our connected app and attempting to run the pull source command says the org needs to have source tracking, etc. etc. Overall it is just very confusing!

Comment: You only need the ID and secret values. You do not package the Connected App at all in this scenario. Packaging one means a new connected app will be created on each install with unique ID and secret. You would then need to somehow make your Web App aware of these new values, which does not make sense in this scenario, IMHO. There are lots of different approaches depending on your overall flow. If just one-way communication is needed, the user login will give the necessary org URL detail (plus others). If two-way comms, you may package a named credential pointing to the Web server etc.

Comment: Interesting and very useful details, thank you. I suppose the issue here is that at some point we want to add other components to the package that modify the SF UI (such as cards on the opportunity screen) that appear under the ISV listing and for our clients to be able to install all of this through one listing (it is my understanding even in this scenario it would still be necessary to perform the OAuth2 flow as well). This would necessitate packaging the connected app though, correct?

Comment: No. You can use feature management to determine the parts of your app a customer can use.